# D3 Force Layout Tick Fn - nodes.attr() is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'm start playing with `D3 Force Layout`, and I'm stuck in adding element and restart the calculation.

Keep on getting: `Uncaught TypeError: network.nodes.attr is not a function`

Here is my code:

```
var topoConfig = {
  width: 600,
  height: 600
};

var network = {
  nodes: [],
  links: []
}

var tickFn = () => {
  network.nodes
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  network.links
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
};

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append('svg')
  .style('width', topoConfig.width + 'px')
  .style('height', topoConfig.height + 'px');

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .nodes(network.nodes)
  .links(network.links)
  .charge(-400)
  .linkDistance(80)
  .size([topoConfig.width, topoConfig.height])
  .on('tick', tickFn);

function reload(){
  var nodes = svg.selectAll('.node')
   .data(network.nodes, d => d.id);

  nodes.enter()
   .append('rect')
   .attr({
      width: 10,
      height: 10,
      x: function(d){return d.x},
      y: function(d){return d.y}
   });

   force.start();
}

function addNode(node){
  network.nodes.push(node);
  reload();
}

window.setTimeout(function(){
  addNode({
    "id": "fabric:a",
    "label": "Fabric Switch",
    "type": "fabric-switch",
    "x": 100,
    "y": 100
  });
}, 500)
```

And here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/teone/wo2gv3ge/3/

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You need a D3 selection to call `.attr()` on, you're calling it on an array.

Answer (score 2):

As Lars mentioned in the comment, `attr` method is available in d3 selections and not in JavaScript arrays.

So you will have to replace your tick function as shown below.

```
var tickFn = () => {
  svg.selectAll('.node') //Where node is the class name of node elements.
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
  svg.selectAll('.link') //Where link is the class name of link elements.
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
};
```

**Note**: Seems like you are using `rect` for repersenting nodes. If nodes are `rect` elements, you should update the `x` and `y` attributes of nodes instead of the `cx` and `cy` attributes. (Use `cx`, `cy` attributes, if the nodes are circle elements)